# Type 'ElementRef' is not generic

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am working with a project using Material Component in Angular 5. I did update my Visual code but I don't know what happened. I am facing an issue "Type 'ElementRef' is not generic."
I have been stuck on this issue since morning.

> Error in this line

```
_inputElement: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
constructor(toggleGroup: MatButtonToggleGroup, _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, _elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>, _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor);
```

Comment: Can you post your full code? It's hard to say what's wrong just by looking at this

Comment: I also have this problem after updating Angular Material to 6.0.0-rc12. Deleted my node_modules thinking it will help but with no luck. My error is in node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts so nothing I can do about it which is very frustrating. Button toggle is something they worked on lately so chances are good that it's a new bug on their side. Try a different RC or wait for the final if you want to work with 6.0. PS: they won't be releasing the final v6 at ng-conf so you'll still have to wait a while.

Comment: @Charl same issue i was facin. I also did delete the node_module and will install again than issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks @bugs issued resolved. Actually the issue was conflicting bootstrap files with material. I uninstall all packges than reinstall again. Issued resolved

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem could be if your you are using Angular Material 6 but still Angular 5 then you will get this error. When installing Angular Material 6 RC 12 it's looking for a peer dependency for Angular 6 Beta 0 while I had a Angular 5.x.x version.

Solution:

1. Downgrade Angular Material to the same major version of Angular (eg. v5.x.x)
2. Upgrade Angular and Material to the latest RC version and live life on the edge. (eg. v6.x.x RCx)

PS: They announced at ng-conf 2018 that from version 6 onwards all the version numbers for Angular, Angular Material and Angular CLI will stay in sync so knowing what goes with what and compatibility will be much easier and hopefully you won't have this problem again.

Answer (score 21):

I was getting the same error as above in `ng-bootstrap` in my Angular 5 application.

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts(58,96):
>   error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.

I had 2.1.0 version in my `package.json` as `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.1.0"`

It seems like the version 2.1.0 is supported in later version, so decided to  downgrade my package `ng-bootstrap` to `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.0"`

And then, when I run `ng s`, everything was working as expected.

Comment: Working like a charm ! Thanks !