# Angular2 : ElementRef is not generic

Tags: angular

I installed ng2 bootstrap..

But I am getting

> node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts(94,30):
>
> error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.

How can I rectify it??

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782273/5995973

Comment: how can we downgrade the version of bootstrap 2.0 to 1.0..

Comment: Uninstall the previous one and then run npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.1.0 --save command.