# What is the fix to the following error while importing MatDialog component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

For the following import

```
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
```

I am getting the following error :

> ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/list.d.ts
>   (26,31): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete.d.ts
>   (83,69): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/line/line.d.ts
>   (20,70): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/line/line.d.ts
>   (28,53): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/option/option.d.ts
>   (64,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple.d.ts
>   (74,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple-renderer.d.ts
>   (77,69): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts
>   (106,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-origin.d.ts
>   (15,17): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-origin.d.ts
>   (18,17): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/badge/typings/badge.d.ts
>   (52,63): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-container.d.ts
>   (39,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts
>   (151,21): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts
>   (174,104): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts
>   (88,20): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts
>   (99,29): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts
>   (46,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts
>   (176,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-input.d.ts
>   (24,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-input.d.ts
>   (55,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/calendar-body.d.ts
>   (65,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker-input.d.ts
>   (84,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts
>   (59,12): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/grid-list/typings/grid-list.d.ts
>   (32,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/grid-list/typings/grid-tile.d.ts
>   (16,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/grid-list/typings/grid-tile.d.ts
>   (30,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/icon/typings/icon.d.ts
>   (86,29): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/text-field/typings/autofill.d.ts
>   (39,22): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/text-field/typings/autofill.d.ts
>   (49,29): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/text-field/typings/autofill.d.ts
>   (58,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/text-field/typings/autosize.d.ts
>   (37,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts
>   (29,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts
>   (100,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/common-behaviors/common-module.d.ts
>   (9,10): Module
>   '"C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"'
>   has no exported member 'HammerLoader'. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/list.d.ts
>   (55,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts
>   (62,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts
>   (125,27): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-directive.d.ts
>   (110,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts
>   (34,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-trigger.d.ts
>   (78,46): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts
>   (184,20): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts
>   (29,100): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts
>   (86,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts
>   (188,49): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/sidenav.d.ts
>   (12,99): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts
>   (93,20): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-container.d.ts
>   (35,47): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts
>   (145,92): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts
>   (11,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts
>   (12,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts
>   (49,89): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts
>   (36,82): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts
>   (42,54): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts
>   (50,54): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/ink-bar.d.ts
>   (34,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts
>   (80,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/typings/tooltip.d.ts
>   (12,10): Module
>   '"C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"'
>   has no exported member 'HammerLoader'. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/typings/tooltip.d.ts
>   (89,49): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tree/typings/node.d.ts
>   (18,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tree/typings/node.d.ts
>   (21,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tree/typings/node.d.ts
>   (33,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tree/typings/node.d.ts
>   (38,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/typings/nested-node.d.ts
>   (33,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/typings/nested-node.d.ts
>   (42,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/typings/tree.d.ts
>   (90,28): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/typings/tree.d.ts
>   (109,30): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic. ERROR in
>   C:/Users/321806119/TableApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree/typings/padding.d.ts
>   (34,95): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "table-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Any fix suggestions ?

Comment: Sure, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please add which version you're using `@angular/material` and `@angular/core`?

Comment: @trichetriche : You mean the code ? I just installed material.io packages and begun with importing the MatDialog and it immediately threw the error upon compilation.

Comment: Post you package.json file, where we can see all versions

Comment: @yurzui : edited

Comment: `ElementRef `became generic only in @angular/core@6.0.0. So you have to use at least 6 version but I would advice you using the same version as @angular/material

Comment: @yurzui  : thanks for pointing out. Is there any lower version of material for popup design utility ? Any documentation links

Comment: There are docs like https://v6.material.angular.io/ for 6.4.7 and https://v5.material.angular.io/ for 5.2.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'ElementRef' is not generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899641/type-elementref-is-not-generic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @yuezui has pointed, `ElementRef` is now a generic property and that you should use the same versions of the Angular CDK/Material and Angular.

You're also using dependencies of different versions. Angular Material v7 should ideally be installed alongside Angular v7.

*(P.S. The following answer is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059399/6782707))*

You should either:

- Update all versions of Angular.

  This can be done by running `ng update @angular/core` which should update all Angular dependencies.

  *(For more info about the `update` command, check out the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/update), or the [Update Angular website](https://update.angular.io))*
- Downgrade your version of the Angular CDK and Angular Material to v4.

  This can be achieved by running the following command:

  ```sh
  npm i @angular/{cdk,material}@'^4.0.0'
  ```

  This command should install version 4 of the CDK and Angular Material.